Quantum Phase Transitions in the Standard Model
I have a background in HEP so before asking the question i wish to explain my level of understanding.
As far as i know, phase transitions studied in condensed matter describe the difference between ordered and disordered phases. When $k_B T \gg \hbar \omega$ we have a thermal (i.e. classical) disorded phase, while otherwise the disordered phase is a quantum one.
A classical phase transition is that connect an ordered phase to a thermally disordered one, while a quantum phase transition connects an ordered phase to a quantum disordered one.
The first one is induced by thermal fluctuation while the second one from quantum ones.
I was wondering what this means for the Standard Model.
I know that thermal fluctuations describe QFT at non-zero temperature, and examples of such classical transitions are the Higgs phase transition, the QCD matter phases/EoS and so on. These are all classical (i.e. thermal) phase transitions of quantum models.
My question is what can we say about quantum (i.e. quantum-fluctuation-induced) phase transitions for the Standard Model.
I suspect it is something related to a transition from quantum to classical behaviour of a system (like a classical limit) but i don't know, order vs disorder doesn't makes much sense to me when talking about the Standard Model.
So,
What phenomena do Quantum Phase Transitions describe in the context of the Standard Model?
Also references about all of this are cery welcomed.

The standard model has phase transitions at temperature $T=0$. For example, there are transitions that occur as a function of the chemical potential $\mu_B$ which is conjugate to the conserved baryon density $\rho_B$. At $\mu_B=0$ (and $T=0$) the density is zero and chiral symmetrie is broken. There is a non-zero $\mu_c>0$ above which the baryon density becomes non-zero and chiral symmetry remains broken. This is the nuclear onset
transition (the transition to self-bound) nuclear matter. There may be larger $\mu_c'$ above which chiral symmetry is restored, or nuclear or quark superfluidity set in (although the details depend sensitively on the flavor content, and are not precisely known).
We can also study the phase structure (at $T=0$) as a function of the quark masses (or, in the full standard model, as a function of the Yukawa couplings). If there are many massless flavors then chiral symmetry may be restored.

"This is the nuclear onset transition (the transition to self-bound) nuclear matter." Is this transition mentioned by you a) chiral symmetry related or b) color confinement related, or both a) and b)? You know,  chiral symmetry breaking and color confinement are two different processes which may or may not happen at the same time.

@MadMax Neither. The onset transition is the transition between nothing (the QCD vacuum) and something (nuclear matter), The order parameter is the baryon density, which changes discontinuously from $\rho=0$ to $\rho=\rho_0$ (the density of nuclear matter).

Is this "nothing" to "something" transition a quantum critical point for both chiral symmetry breaking and color confinement? Do you consider color confinement as a quantum phase transition? Or do you consider color confinement per se is not a quantum phase transition phenomenon, but confinement accidentally coincides with the chiral symmetry breaking quantum critical point?

In other words, do color confinement and  chiral symmetry breaking ALWAYS happen together? Or are they allowed to occur separately at least in principle?

@MadMax  see here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/370363/8554

In the Standard Model, the chiral symmetry breaking process of QCD is a nice example of quantum phase transition, which is "quantum-fluctuation-induced" rather than "thermal-fluctuation-induced". In the quantum ordered phase, the chiral symmetry is dynamically broken, and the pions are the corresponding (pseudo-) Nambu–Goldstone bosons.
Since QCD is a notoriously hard to calculate in the low-energy limit, a fairly good effective theory of the above quantum phase transition is the Nambu–Jona-Lasinio model (see Wiki page here). The four-fermion interaction in NJL model is parametrized by the coupling constant $g$, which more or less corresponds to the QCD coupling constant $\alpha_{QCD}$. The quantum phase transition is characterized a critical coupling constant $g_c$, which demarcates the boundary between quantum ordered phase and quantum disordered phase. When $g$ exceeds a critical value $g > g_c$, the system is in a quantum ordered phase, thus the chiral symmetry is broken and there is a chiral condensate (which is different from color confinement). When $g$ is below the critical value $g < g_c$, the system is in a quantum disordered phase (with unbroken chiral symmetry) without chiral condensate.

This is clearly ChatGPT generated, it is the english translational sentence by sentence of the below ChatGPT answer.

In real QCD, however, the strong coupling runs, and there is no obvious sense in which there is a quantum critical point $g=g_c$

@LolloBoldo, I wrote each sentence by myself and never consulted ChatGPT for the answer. Please double check your facts before lodging accusations. On the other hand, I take your criticism as a compliment in disguise, since I as a mere mortal human can generate AI-level content, what an achievement! BTW, by your peculiar logic, do you think this response to you is also generated by ChatGPT ;)

@Thomas, point taken. For the case of condensed matter, you have some freedom to fine-tune some parameter to be in the vicinity of the critical value to study the quantum critical point. For example, for cuprate High-Tc superconductor you can adjust the "doping" or in graphine superconductor you can twist the "angle". However, in QCD the parameters are already fixed by the Almighty. I don't have the freedom to do the tweaking and twisting so that I can observe the quantum critical point in a lab. That is what it is, I can't play the role of the Almighty.

@MadMax my comment was originated in response to a previous answer (now deleted i see) that was in fact written with AI, and was nearly identical to yours, same logical order of arguments/presentation, same order of sentences, and almost identical punctuation in each sentence and a lot other similarities. If you tell it's written by you i believe you, but now i feel scared since it means that AI responses on very technical topics have already pratically indistinguishable from human texts! I would love to show you the other answer so that you could see where my suspicion was coming from :)

@LolloBoldo This is the deleted comment https://pastebin.com/Bvk3jfmq

@LolloBoldo, now I am really intrigued by the mystery and want to get to the bottom of the matter. Could you please show the EXACT WORDING of the other answer that "was in fact written with AI, and was nearly identical to yours, same logical order of arguments/presentation, same order of sentences". Or Michelll Porter can play detective and help dig out the other answer and copy/paste the exact wording here (not a link). This is becoming more and more interesting.
